# fnmatch function with two regex parameters

Tags: python, regex, unix

Can we use `fnmatch` with two regular expressions?

For example, if I use `fnmatch("file*", "*", 0)`, will it match in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, if I use `fnmatch("file*", "*", 0)`, will it match in this
>   case?

Yes, of course it will, once you remove the redundant third parameter:

```
>>> from fnmatch import fnmatch
>>> fnmatch("file*", "*")
True
```

However, it is **not** matching because it's interpreting both arguments as regular expressions; it matches because the pattern `"*"` will match *any input* for `filename`, including `"file*"`. You can see this in [the source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/fnmatch.py#l83):

```
return re_pat.match(name) is not None
```

`name` (which is `filename`, the first argument to `fnmatch`) isn't being used as a regex, it's just the string that gets passed to `re.match`.

You can also see from the code that the second argument, the `pattern`, is translated rather than being used directly as a regular expression, as the *"Unix shell-style wildcards"* syntax is not regex. I suggest you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html).

> Can we use `fnmatch` with two regular expressions?

No, we can't.

Answer (score 1):

No. Patterns for fnmatch are NOT regular expressions - they are "Unix shell-style wildcards" according to the python standard lib documents

Answer (score 0):

`fnmatch` is for matching filenames to "shell-style" expression (not regex to be clear). I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish, but in short, no. You need to give it a specific filename and then a pattern to match it to, it doesn't try to see if two patterns are consistent.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use `fnmatch` like that. They are not regex in the way you are using it. You need to give it a specific filename and then a pattern to match it to, it doesn't try to see if two patterns are consistent.